Go runtime getsockopt for linux 386
Is there a way to call getsockopt passing arbitrary byte buffer from a user program in golang for linux 386?
There are several exported functions regarding getsockopt in syscall_unix.go in unix package (golang.org/x/sys/unix)
but there are no exported version which can pass arbitrary byte buffer to getsockopt.
Moreover the low level functions getsockopt and socketfunc are not exported.

There appears to be nothing appropriate neither in the stock syscall nor in golang.org/x/sys/unix. But you can easily roll your own: a syscall on Linux is a number identifying the syscall (note that they're different for 386 and amd64!) and a calling convention (so called ABI). The ABI is handled by Go compiler, and the number is available from the packags being discussed. So basically you take the code of any definition of Getsockopt* (say, GetsockoptString looks OK) and write your own which works with the caller-supplied slice.

To make my point more clear: if you'll look at the definitons of all those Getsockopt* functions, you'll not they all follow a common pattern: allocate a buffer of the expected length then pass its address to the syscall; and each of the functions uses the same syscall number (per GOARCH).

For 386 each of the Getsockopt* functions call getsockopt which in turn calls socketcall and both of them are not exported so I can not use them in my own package.

@George, The getsockopt are just helpers wrapping the raw syscalls. You can make any syscall you want directly with the unix.Syscall* functions.

@JimB yes I use these unix.Syscall* for the other architectures. I was wondering if I can use them for 386 given that the implementation of the Getsockopt* functions in go runtime for 386 does not use the Syscall* functions.

@George, to my knowledge, golang.org/x/sys/unix is not limited to certain arches, so supposedly yes, you can. In either way, stock syscall provides 90% of helpers x/sys/unix implements.

@kostix Having this comment in syscall_linux_386.go:
  `// On x86 Linux, all the socket calls go through an extra indirection,`. 
  `// I think because the 5-register system call interface can't handle`. 
  `// the 6-argument calls like sendto and recvfrom. Instead the`. 
  `// arguments to the underlying system call are the number below`. 
  `// and a pointer to an array of uintptr. We hide the pointer in the`. 
  `// socketcall assembly to avoid allocation on every system call.`. 

I think I can not use Syscall* funcs directly.

@kostix Actually there is the same comment for s390x arch. There, the Getsockopt* function are implemented in a different way. I strongly suppose that the same approach can be used for x86.
